# What are the elements in the subgroup generated by $\langle(1234)\rangle$ in $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

What are the elements in the subgroup generated by $\langle(1234)\rangle$ in $S_4$?

Comment: $\langle(1234)\rangle$ ***is*** a subgroup of $S_4$; it is the subgroup generated by the element $(1234)$. Therefore, the subgroup generated by $\langle(1234)\rangle$ is just $\langle(1234)\rangle$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the element $(1234)$. It has order $4$, hence $<(1234)>$ has 4 elements : the identity, $(1234)$, $(1234)^2=(13)(24)$, $(1234)^3=(1432)$.